# web based games done in ruby, point me in the right direction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resources

So I've been using a number of educational software web based apps, they are games, and they are all using flash. Recently I've seen some posts about making games with ruby. Are there any good examples out there for making games with ruby. I know of the game library, and then there is one book on amazon that has some awful reviews, and then there is manofcode, but I haven't seen some good examples or tuts.

So if you know of a good resource for learning web based game development with ruby post some links please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Railsrumble project from Ryan Bates : [GovsGo](http://github.com/ryanb/govsgo)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create client-side games you shouldn't look at ruby. Try a good Javascript solution like [GameQuery](http://gamequery.onaluf.org/).

You could use Ruby (and Rails) on the server side to keep track of scores et cetera.

Comment: Using Rails to work with the db is the plan and us flash to play the games and get data and then connect friends is the plan, i was just curious if there was ruby solution.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's technically not a game, I used [Gosu](http://code.google.com/p/gosu/wiki/RubyTutorial) for [zombie-chaser](http://github.com/agrimm/zombie-chaser).

Comment: can you post an example link please

Comment: @Sam: I've added hyperlinks to `Gosu` and to `zombie-chaser`

Answer (score 0):

There was a project "HotRuby" where you should have been able to create Flash/ActionScript using Ruby. But I don't know if the development is going on.